# Object of type date is not JSON serializable error, while uploading dataframe to bigquery?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a dataframe from python to biguquery. I get the following error.

**Object of type date is not JSON serializable**

Below is the sample dataframe.

```
product_id  01/05/19    02/05/19    03/05/19
1             187668    191568      189098
2             331527    341754      340158
3             68904      65808      65484
4             32500      38012      36816
5             82677      92106       92148
```

Comment: Could you please show us how you are trying to upload the dataframe?

Comment: df.to_gbq('db_name.table_name', project_id='xyz', if_exists='append', verbose=False)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the labels of the columns to an acceptable [column name](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names):

> Column names
>
> A column name must contain only letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore. The maximum column name length is 128 characters.

You can do so by using the `table_schema` argument of `to_gbq`:

```
 df.to_gbq('db_name.table_name', 
           project_id='xyz', 
           if_exists='append', 
           verbose=False, 
           table_schema=[{'name': '_' + str(col).replace('-','_'), 'type': 'INT64'} 
                         for col in df.columns]
 )
```